# wireshark installation using source code

Tags: software-installation

i downloaded `wireshark-1.8.0rc2.tar.bz2` and copied it to `/opt/wireshark` directory and uncompressed it by

`sudo tar -xjvf wireshark-1.8.0rc2.tar.bz2`

then by doing `ls` in the extracted folder, i found the configure file.

Then i did `./configure` then i got this problem:

```
  configure: error: I couldn't find yacc (or bison or ...); 
    make sure it's installed and in your path.
```

how to fix it?

Comment: It is highly recommended to install it from **official repository** since it is `specifying Dependencies`.

Answer (score 10):

In case someone runs into this in the future: you can just `sudo apt-get install bison`

Bison will provide yacc to Wireshark via `update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/bison.yacc to provide /usr/bin/yacc (yacc) in auto mode`

Also, if you install Bison, you'll also need `sudo apt-get install flex` since it will ask for it afterwards. And while you're at it, you should `sudo apt-get install libpcap-dev` too, since it will probably need pcap.h, and it comes in the -dev package, not the regular one.

After this, it should be the usual `make`, wait... and then `make install` and you're done. Depending on your specs, the wait part might be 5 minutes, just to build the parlay package.

Comment: Very thoughtful reply from alonso.ss. Also, one might get a configuration error about GTK+ and Glib versions, like I did (Ubuntu 12.04). In that case, install `libgtk2.0-dev` and `libglib2.0-dev`.

Comment: And I'm just sitting here going *wink* *wink* at the screen. So many commands to input. So much to configure.

Answer (score 3):

Wireshark is available in the software repositories. Try running `sudo apt-get install wireshark` in the terminal (`ctrl+alt+t`) to install it with the dependencies you were missing. Although, you might need to [enable the universe repositories](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#Adding_Ubuntu_Software_Repositories).

Question for you though...
Is there a specific reason you're trying to build from source ?

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is you seeking is

```
sudo apt-get install bison
```

which already alfonso.ss mentioned. But reason for adding another answer is because although you fulfill this dependencies you will face another dependency errors. Such as qt errors etc. To avoid all the dependencies, I suggest you to run below command.

> sudo apt-get install bison flex libpcap-dev qt5-default qttools5-dev
>   libssl-dev libgtk-3-dev

After this you will get no other dependency error.
refer below link for further details
https://menukablog.wordpress.com/2016/02/29/install-wireshark-using-source-code-in-ubuntu/

Answer (score 2):

In 2020, I had to install the following on Ubuntu <kbd>18.04</kbd> to build Wireshark <kbd>3.2.4</kbd>

```
apt install libgcrypt20-dev 
apt install lex
apt install bison
apt install flex libpcap-dev 
apt install libpcap-dev
apt install pcaputils 
apt install libssh-gcrypt-dev   # Or libssh-dev ? (not both)
apt install bison flex 
apt install libpcap-dev
apt install qt5-default qttools5-dev libssl-dev libgtk-3-dev
apt install libqt5opengl5-dev 
apt install qtmultimedia5-dev 
apt install libqt5svg5-dev
```

based on various research...

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking at this now, `qt` is no longer in `apt`/`apt-get` sources by default, so you'll need to build it yourself.

https://wiki.qt.io/Install_Qt_5_on_Ubuntu says:

> . . . due to policy change, distributing Open Source Qt linux package is discontinue from 5.15.0. You need to build your own package starting from 5.15.0.

You can find the build instructions for Qt5 here: https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_5_from_Git